# Jenkins Shell Scripting issue

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, helm3, yq

I try to get an information out of a helm file in Jenkins. For this I do:

```
helm history adt-development -n adt-development --max 1 --output yaml
```

to get the value ".chart" inside the helm yaml output I use yq

```
yq ".chart"
```

Because there is a bad yaml file reported, a "-" is too much at the beginning I try to cut it.

However, how to write this command in jenkins shell tofill a variable?

I tried:

```
helmvalue=$(helm history pro-development -n pro-development --max 1 --output yaml) | cut -c2- | yq '-chart'
```

But yq will read the output with the "-" so it ignore the cut output.
Any idea how to

- read helm information -> cut first 2 char -> read .chart from output before.

On request additional information:
reported by helm:

```
- app_version: 0.6.0 
  chart: prof-1.0.1-2022-03-02-1616-46eb101842db6e367f3cd9ab42636ee9bf7d4912 
  description: Upgrade complete 
  revision: 355 
  status: deployed 
  updated: '"2022-03-02T16:42:52.04760689+01:00"'
```

Output from yq:

```
Error: bad file '-': yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Comment: Can you post the YAML with that incorrect character?

Comment: I have added the information

Comment: Which yq version are you using? - See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info. The Go yq (aka mikefarah yq) is able read this YAML without any issues

Answer (score 1):

In `YAML` syntax, the dash sign `-` introduces a list of key-value objects, which by `yq` is converted into an array. Access it using `.[]`.

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), use

```sh
yq '.[].chart'
```

With [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), add the `-r` option to generate raw text

```sh
yq -r '.[].chart'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the intent and syntax correctly,

`helmvalue=$(helm history pro-development -n pro-development --max 1 --output yaml)`
is stored in a variable; there is no output to `stdout`.
Which means `<some cmd output> | cut -c2-` has no input from `stdin` to the `cut` command and then no input to `yq`.

```
helmvalue=$(helm history pro-development -n pro-development --max 1 --output yaml| cut -c2-| yq '-chart')
```

Move closing bracket ")" to end and:

- `helm history ... -output yaml` will send to `stdout`
- `cut -c2-` will process `stdin`, cut 2 chars and send to `stdout`
- `yq '-chart` should process from stdin a series of colon separated values and output a helmchart (?) to stdout
  `helmvalue=$(...)` will contain the output from above
  helmval